# No info about RAM in CPU-Z for msi prestige ps42?

Tags: windows, memory, cpu-z

I need to update my RAM from 8 Gigs to 16Gigs for that I need to find my RAM frequency and other details but CPU-Z gives me no information about this.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to find my RAM details ?

Comment: Look at the sticks and their stickers. Check your BIOS.

Comment: Just checked the BIOS, No additional info and I dont wanna open my laptop without a RAM in hand.

Comment: You should look at the SPD tab for information about the RAM. The memory tab only gives the current timings. Indicentally, I have the same machine but it does show this information in CPU-Z. It has an 8GB Low Voltage DDR4-2666 SoDIMM, CL19. Be aware there is only one SoDIMM slot, so you should look for a 16GB module with the same characteristics (or better) to replace the 8GB one.

Comment: @StarCat Thanks for the help, Found the info under SPD tab, My spec sheet says that max of 16GB RAM supported. Can I go for Kingston hyperX or any other brand you advise ?

Comment: I found this on amazon "HyperX Kingston Technology Impact 16GB 2666 MHz DDR4 CL15 260-Pin Sodimm Laptop Memory"

Comment: I don't advise any particular brand or type of memory. Going by the specifications, the one you found looks like it would work.